# How to call parent class attributes in child class if they are of same name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Parent"

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = "Child"

    def print_names(self):
        print("Child name:", self.name)

    # Below line of code is giving error
        print("Parent name:", super().name)
```

Suppose we have two classes Parent and Child, Child inherit Parent class. Both have same attribute name, but when I am calling super().name , it is giving error Please help

Comment: Child instance attributes of the same name as a parent attribute are always overwritten.

Comment: If you need values of both `Parent` and `Child` `name` it's a sign that maybe those objects should have a different relationship - for example, composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Unlike C++, there *is* only one instance attribute, `name`. It happens to be set by both `Parent.__init__` and `Child.__init__`; the final value depends on the order in which the two methods are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an object of child class it will override and will always give you
Child
Instead create a object of Parent class and call its attribute

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Parent"

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Child"

    def print_names(self):
        print("Child name:", self.name)

        p = Parent()
        print("Parent name:", p.name)

c1 = Child()
c1.print_names()
```

`'Child name: Child'`
`'Parent name: Parent'`

Along with this you can have a look of at this playlist it explains OOP in most easy way
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAvWroJsSxGn4LOCLdxL4HjUije65mP5K

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It's working fine but could you please correct the indentation of method in Parent class and we don't need super.__init__() in the __init__ of child class as it created extra line of code and confusion.